# Can't get Python Pygame object to change direction

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I can't get my object in Pygame to change direction in my code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 900
height = 700
background_image = pygame.image.load("board.png")
background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (900, 700))

virus_pic = pygame.image.load("virus.png")
trojanvirus_pic = pygame.image.load("trojan_virus.png")
armouredvirus_pic = pygame.image.load("armoured_virus.png")

antivirus_pic = pygame.image.load("antivirus.png")
trojanantivirus_pic = pygame.image.load("trojan_antivirus.png")
armouredantivirus_pic = pygame.image.load("armoured_antivirus.png")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Anti Virus")

#def anitvirus():

def virus(x_virus,y_virus):
    screen.blit(virus_pic, (x_virus, y_virus))

def intro():
    background_image = pygame.image.load("intro_background.png")
    background_image = pygame.transform.scale(background_image, (900, 700))
    logo_image = pygame.image.load("logo.png")
    logo_image = pygame.transform.scale(logo_image, (600, 200))

    pygame.display.update()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    main()

        screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(logo_image, (width/2-300,100))

        pygame.display.update()

def main():
    x_virus = 0
    y_virus = 70

    pygame.display.update()
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()

        screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

        if x_virus != 320:
            x_virus += 1
            virus(x_virus,y_virus)

        if x_virus == 320:
            if y_virus != 400:
                y_virus += 1
                virus(x_virus,y_virus)

        if y_virus == 400:
            if x_virus != 500:
                x_virus += .5
                virus(x_virus,y_virus)

        if x_virus == 500:
            if y_virus != 10:
                y_virus -= 1
                virus(x_virus,y_virus)
```

Here is the code that does the movement of the game ^

```
        pygame.display.update()
intro()
```

I don't know if all of the if statements is the most effective way to do this. I have tried different things but the if statements seem to work for the most part. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not blitting the image correctly. Let's take a look at this function:

```
def virus(x_virus,y_virus):
    screen.blit(virus_pic, (x_virus, y_virus))
```

you take in the x and y coordinates and attempt to blit `virus_pic` to `screen`. the thing is you're not accounting for the different scope here, you need to pass `screen` and `virus_pic` as parameters, otherwise your function doesn't know what they are, so change your function to look like this

```
def virus(screen,virus_pic,x_virus,y_virus):
    screen.blit(virus_pic, (x_virus, y_virus))
```

and then change the corresponding section of code in your `main()` function. I've taken the liberty of simplifying it a little as well

```
    if x_virus != 320:
        x_virus += 1

    if x_virus == 320:
        if y_virus != 400:
            y_virus += 1

    if y_virus == 400:
        if x_virus != 500:
            x_virus += .5

    if x_virus == 500:
        if y_virus != 10:
            y_virus -= 1

    virus(screen,virus_pic,x_virus,y_virus)
```

let me know how it goes!

EDIT:

The reason it's not changing direction is because at each frame, it's coordinates are only being altered by the same exact values each time, therefore, the velocity vector stays unchanged and you only see movement in one direction.

You need to find a way to make those changes be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot, but it doesn't really help my problem.